# Swift detect Dutch location/address in non-editable UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

So I'm developing an app to display some information to a user.

I'm trying to get an address to display as a link to a user and allow the user to navigate to a location when clicking on it. The easiest way is to use a UITextView for this and using this method I have been able to get the UITextView to detect a phone number and URL, however not a location/address.

I set the text in the following way:

```
locationLabel.scrollEnabled = true
locationLabel.text = est.getAddressString()
locationLabel.makeAddress()
locationLabel.sizeToFit()
locationLabel.scrollEnabled = false
```

The makeAddress method does the following:

```
internal func makeAddress() {
    // see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDataDetectorTypes
    dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Address

    var mutString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
    mutString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, mutString.length))
    self.attributedText = mutString
}
```

The address I have to detect is for example: Albinusdreef 2 2333ZA Leiden Netherlands. However the UITextView does not seem to be able to do this.

**EDIT**

Is it the formatting of the address that I have to adjust maybe? or is it just like with Android and can it only detect US addresses? (just tested and US address worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the region on your phone to a different one, e.g. the Dutch one, it does work. But how can a foreigner, having a different region, see this as a link then. Would one have to improvise something themselves?

**Edit**

It would be useful to know exactly what formatting is required by Apple. For instance "1234AB" does not work properly and "1234 AB" does